# Concatenate Multiple Cells with different data types

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to concatenate three cells on two sheets into one cell.

- On `Sheet 1` I have `Cell A1` with value `PERFECT`.
- On `Sheet 2` I have `Cell A1` with date `JAN-2016`.
- On `Sheet 2` I have `Cell B2` with value `JAN-2017`.

What I want is `PERFECT JAN-2016 - JAN-2017`

Please help

Comment: This seems fairly straightforward.  What research have you done, and what have you learned from it?  What have you tried, and what happened?  What part do you need help with?

Comment: On sheet 2, are the values text or dates formatted to display month and year?

Answer (score 0):

Just put the following formula :

```
=Sheet1!A1&" "&Sheet2!A1&" "&Sheet2!B2
```

You will have to change the cell A1 in Sheet2 and the cell B2 in Sheet2 to **Text** so the date does not convert to numbers.